# Tkinter - Canvas Text Object Auto-Scroll

Tags: python, canvas, text, tkinter, autoscroll

I'm working on a Tkinter application with a `Canvas` and a `create_text` object drawn on top of this `Canvas`.

This text object word wraps automatically through the `width` property. However, I would like this text to automatically clip the top line of the text when the text object wraps to a 4th line.

So go from this:

```
 aaaa
bbbbbb
 cccc
dddddd <- incoming new text
```

To this:

```
bbbbbb
 cccc
dddddd
```

Any good way to do this?

Comment: does it need to be in a canvas? Also you may be able to use an if/else statement to check if there are 4 lines and if so remove the 1st line and move the other 3 up one row. I think it could be done in a textbox.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the premade ScrolledText widget?

Comment: OK so there's no way to do this in a Canvas text object? Only other types of text objects?

Comment: The only way to do it is to write the code to do it yourself. It wouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @Novel
Well, I have been trying. The issue is that there is no way to know 1) when the text object has wordwrapped to a third line and 2) how many characters are in the topmost line so that I can remove them. If you have any suggestions I would love to hear them.

Comment: You don't have to remove part of a line, you can just look at the size of it text object and move it up the appropriate amount. I could do this, but I need to be convinced that there is a point to this over just using a ScrolledText widget.

Comment: From what I've read on the docs, a ScrolledText widget seems to be a text area with a visible scrollbar on the side. What I'm doing is more akin to subtitles, its an alpha overlay of text that changes as the program runs. So, I don't want the text to just move upwards, but instead shift one line up and have the topmost line simply disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any good way to do this?

No, there is no way to cause canvas text items to clip the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply scroll the Text widget.

See the code here: https://github.com/decadenza/blondieautoscroll